# javascript - stop fixed element from scrolling after certain point without jquery

Tags: javascript, css

I know there are many solutions to stopping an element from scrolling after a certain point using JQuery, but I'd like to do it with vanilla Javascript.

Basically, this is an element that fixes once you scroll down to it and I want it to stop being fixed at the bottom of the page so that it doesn't go under the footer, if that makes sense.

Here is my current Javascript:

```
var fixmeTop = $('#childWidth').offset().top; //get initial position

$(window).scroll(function() {
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop - 100) {           // fix once scroll to or past element 

        var elementAdd = document.getElementById("childWidth");
        elementAdd.classList.add("afix");

} else {  
    var elementRemove = document.getElementById("childWidth");
    elementRemove.classList.remove("afix");  
}
});
```

The CSS which fixes the element:

```
.afix {
    position:fixed;
    z-index;9999;
    top:100px;
}
```

I tried getting #childWidth's distance from the bottom of the page and then adding a CSS class with `position:absolute;` once scrolled within a certain distance from the bottom of the page but the element just disappeared once I scrolled down to near the bottom.

Comment: You might want to look into [tether](http://tether.io/).

Comment: Replace all of your jquery calls to the equivalent found here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).  This would be a pure CSS solution; no JS necessary:

```css
.HolyGrail {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.HolyGrail-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}

.HolyGrail-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.HolyGrail-nav, .HolyGrail-ads {
  /* 12em is the width of the columns */
  flex: 0 0 12em;
  background-color: red;
}

.HolyGrail-nav {
  /* put the nav on the left */
  order: -1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

header, footer { height: 100px; }
header { background-color: blue; }
footer { background-color: green; }

.nav-box-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.nav-box {
  background-color: magenta;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/ -->
<div class="HolyGrail">
  <header>…</header>
  <div class="HolyGrail-body">
    <main class="HolyGrail-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. In dictum non </p>
      <p>consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed 
      <p>Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices 
      <p>tincidunt arcu. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor 
      <p>posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa.</p>
    </main>
    <nav class="HolyGrail-nav">
      <div class="nav-box-wrapper">
        <div class="nav-box">
          <ul>
            <li>link 1</li>
            <li>link 2</li>
            <li>link 3</li>
            <li>link 4</li>
            <li>link 5</li>
            <li>link 6</li>
            <li>link 7</li>
            <li>link 8</li>
            <li>link 9</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <aside class="HolyGrail-ads">…</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>…</footer>
</div>
```

Please excuse all the ugly lorem ipsum -- if you run this full screen you should be able to see it in action.

This was sort of quick slipshod together-- there might be better approaches, and you'd want to do plenty of browser testing.  But the `sticky` position property would probably allow what you are describing without the need for any code outside your HTML and CSS.